# Keep the font awesome spinner icon from at the original place

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

When I put the icon `fa fa-spinner fa-spin` the icon starts itself rotating. Although the spinning dots rotate fine.

Ex :- http://farzikam.cf/a click the submit button and see

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by removing the top / bottom padding from your buttons icon

```
<button id="btn" onclick="load()">
  <div id="btntext">Submitting</div>
  <i id="plus" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="padding: 0;margin-left: 7px;"></i> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from your icon and add a margin to your button text like:

```
#btntext{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

You should also use classes instead of id´s for that case.

Answer (score 0):

> **Add** this CSS and it should work fine....

```
#btn .fa-spin {
    padding: 0;
}
#btntext {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```